# Chrome font rendering incorrectly in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde

Fonts in Chrome 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) in Ubuntu 20.04 KDE Plasma are often appearing white or multicolored.  See four examples below.  One is text typed into the search bar on the linkedin website.  The second example is text typed into gmail. The third is askubuntu.com while typing this very moment.  The fourth is rainbow coloring while visiting askubuntu.com.  I have refreshed the font cache using fc-cache, but that did not help.  I have also tried starting google-chrome-stable with and without "--use-gl=desktop --ignore-gpu-blocklist".  The improperly rendered fonts flicker whenever the page is scrolled.

[image: fonts rendered white in gmail]

[image: fonts rendered white]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome, I solved this issue by:

1. Reseting all flags (chrome://flags/)
2. (chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization) has to be set to Disabled to fix Fonts rendering issue. The default option is not always is 'Disabled'.

Comment: This answer fixes the issue definitelly.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem myself.  On the Fonts page in System Settings make two adjustments:

1. Uncheck Force font DPI (is was checked and set to 96)
2. Set Sub-pixel rendering to None (it was set to RGB).

With these changes, chrome fonts render properly.